# Nginx Fails to connect when Upstream resolves to IPv6

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configurations in nginx that perform proxy_pass to google-analytics.com. But as you know google-analytics same times resolves to ipv4 and at times to ipv6 when it does resolve to ipv6 nginx fails with this error.

connect() to [2a00:xxx:xxx:809::xxx]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream. ( I just obfuscated the real ip of the upstream)

upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream

Why does nginx faile with upstream in proxy_pass resolves to ipv6?

```
server {
     server_name upstream.nmmapper.com;
     location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
     }
}
location = /analytics.js {
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the piece of server block.

Comment: I just updated to include some sample code block

Answer (score 5):

To always connect over IPv4 you need to add a [`resolver` with `ipv6=off`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

However, Nginx is doing DNS resolution at startup by default.

Include (an empty) variable in the hostname to force Nginx to do resolution at runtime with the specified resolver directive.

```js
location / {
    resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off valid=30s;
    set $empty "";
    proxy_pass https://example.com$empty;
}
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/1006465/242991.

In your case this should work:

```js
location = /analytics.js {
    resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off valid=30s;
    set $empty "";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js$empty;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ipv6 `listen [::]:80` directive:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80; 
  server_name upstream.nmmapper.com;
  ...
}
```

For ssl:

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
```

Comment: I have applied the changes, I will see what happens then I will post back if it works

Comment: We had the same issue trying to proxy to firebase storage and this did not fix it. The URL is resolving to an ipv6 address and we get the same "Network Unreachable" error when nginx tries to contact it.

Comment: @kmgt Are you able to explain why this should work? I ask since this is telling the server to *listen* on the ipv6 localhost at port 80, but the question asker's issue was relating to proxy pass to an upstream server that happens to resolve to an ipv6 address.